# Changing ability to access via "localhost"

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, localhost

I've successfully used PHP/Apache/MySQL on my iMac several times in the past few months/years. However, I started using a new PHP book and moved things around a bit (obviously without knowing what I thought I was doing!) I managed to get localhost working about a week ago. I had to stop work on this project until late today. Once again, using a saved bookmark for phpMySql today, I got the infamous "cannot connect to localhost." message.

To make this somewhat shorter, I can now access localhost again. Whew! Here's my hosts file:

```
10.0.1.2    localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# fe80::1%lo0   localhost
```

Firstly, I have no idea what that last, commented out line is for, but I'll search the net after posting this.

Secondly, the 10.0.1.2 used to appear in the "Web Sharing" Pref Panel. Now it has my computerName/~username.

Finally, although localhost is working (and I changed the bookmark for it), `apachectl -t` shows this response:

> httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName

I thought from reading that this indicated the use of IPv6 but turning that OFF in Network PP doesn't seem to make any difference in the response from Apache.

As you can see, I know just enough to be dangerous, fortunately only to myself, I hope!

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, your hosts file is incorrect, and can cause problems.

Localhost is always 127.0.0.1. That is a special IP address used only for that. It is the address that the network adapter uses to communicate internally.

You should change the DNS name for 10.0.1.2 to something other than "localhost".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Another way to look at localhost is that it is a generic way of saying "this computer" when you put it in the URL box.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried 127.0.0.1 since I'd seen that mentioned in my searching. But I don't think it helped/worked. I used 10.0.1.2 because that is what I see in my Network Pref Panel as the IP for this machine. However, I agree that it can change depending on when it starts up compared to others on my LAN. OTOH, it is the only machine directly connected to the cable router (others are via WiFi). Without restarting the machine, I'm seeing the same message in Terminal (using ::1 for ServerName) but I can still access phpMyAdmin. A thunderstorm is approaching...I'll shut down. Thanks!

Comment: You can use any DNS name for the IP of your computer, but localhost IS 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Found this: "fe80::1 is typically used as the "localhost" address--the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1." at [this SU thread](http://superuser.com/questions/241642/what-is-the-relevance-of-fe801lo0-localhost-in-etc-hosts) from @eater. (still trying to learn this Markdown formatting, sorry) Another confirmation of your "localhost IS 127..." ;-) Thanks

Comment: Right, and 127.0.0.1 is the IPv4 loopback/localhost address.

Comment: OK, guys, I get the picture. I just commented out my "10.0.1.2" line as I don't know enough to need/use it right now. I think I have finally got things back in working order, including several configuration settings in config.inc.php. Thanks for all your kind and non-confrontational responses to my lack of knowledge...hat not always the case when speaking to experts! ;-) Now, how do I give you guys "up" votes? 8-)

Comment: You do not quite the rep to upvote (15), but you can mark the answer by clicking the check mark. That will add two to your rep and put you at 13.